# SAS EG - Individual Datasets split by date vs Single appended dataset containing all dates

Tags: sas, processing-efficiency, enterprise-guide

This is mainly a question about efficiency, as I'm unfamiliar with how SAS processes datasets. A lot of code that I run reads from multiple datasets with consecutive dates (whether this is consecutive months/quarters/years depends on the datasets).

At the moment, the codes require manual updates each time they're run to ensure they're picking up the correct dates, so I would have something such as:

```
Data Quarters;
Set XYZ_201803
    XYZ_201806
    ...
    ...
    XYZ_202006;
Run;
```

To help tidy up the code and make it a bit less tedious, I've approached a few different ideas and had a few sent my way and one of the big ideas is to store all of the XYZ_YYYYMM datasets as a single, appended dataset, so they can be read from with a simple filter on the date as below:

```
Data Quarters;
Set AppendedData;
Where Date > 201812;
Run;
```

Which of these two options is more efficient as far as computation goes? On datasets which are typically a couple of gb in size, which would you recommend? What other pros and cons come with each idea?

Thanks for any input. :)

Comment: We've used a combination of approaches. We keep a master big data set that has the most recent 3 years of data and then the historical stuff is split into smaller data sets. This means if anyone needs all of the data it's there but they can also very quickly work with the big data set if needed. And those aren't your only options - you could also design a macro or dynamic naming so that you aren't manually updating the dates each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely a single dataset and several separate datasets will be similar from a performance standpoint; there is some small overhead opening new datasets, but as long as it's not thousands of them you probably won't notice a difference.

There will be a performance hit with a single dataset in *creating* that dataset, and in *using* that dataset, if you use only small sections usually.  Typically, separate datasets are common where people usually do analysis of individual quarters, and rarely combine them.

Finally, if the datasets can vary from quarter to quarter in their contents (if the formats could change, if the fields can change), then having separate is easier in some ways than having to manage the change between the different periods.

That said, there's a huge *organizational* benefit to a single dataset, and all of the above issues can be dealt with.  Think of SAS datasets as large SQL tables - they are effectively the same, and the same things that help SQL tables can help SAS.  Proper sizing of columns, proper sorting of the stored data, indexing appropriately, are all important solutions.  If you have a database team at your place of work, they may be able to help construct an ideal table plan.  Files of several GB can definitely benefit from indexing and proper sorting, to allow users to easily get at the bits they need.

If you were to stay with separate datasets, you can use the macro language to make sure you're reading in the right datasets, assuming they're named in a consistent fashion.  That might be the ideal solution if there are other reasons to stay separate - then no changes are needed each quarter.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks very much for this, as it helps address both sides of my question. I'm unsure of how this data is used outside of the current review I'm putting together, so that would definitely be a good idea for me to check out. I believe, due to the nature of the data, the tables are kept identical, quarter on quarter, so there appears to be a good argument for creating a single, appended table.

Answer (score 1):

Points of interest:

- From a coding standpoint

  - Dealing with a single, stacked data set, created by appending the quarterly data sets is more efficient.
- From a resource standpoint

  - Have to make sure you have large enough disk to hold the single large table
  - Have additional off storage to hold the original pieces -- no need to clutter up the primary data disk with all the pieces.
  - A 2TB SSD is very fast, remarkably cheap, and low power and can contain a table comprised of quite a few "couple GB" pieces.

    - Spinning disk has lower $/TB and more capacity.  I/O will be slower and consume more power.

To further improve query performance you will want to index the variables most commonly used in `BY`, `CLASS`, and `WHERE` statements.

"... simple filter ..." is part of "Keep it Simple S****" (KISS)